Is the vectorization of a matrix-t distribution a multivariate-t distribution?
As I mention in the title, I would like to know whether the vectorized version of a matrix variate-t distribution is a multivariate-t distribution. If that is the case, how can we express the parameters from the latter distribution in terms of the parameters from the former distribution? References on the subject would be quite appreciated.
